# Neopets Stock Market - What are ALL of the Tickers

Tags: neopets

I'm currently working on a database, and I'd like to use the ticker names as the columns, so I need to know all of the tickers, including the ones that are at zero. Does anyone have a list?

Comment: Anybody else find the find that Neopets has a stock market a little scary? Sure changed a lot since I played last...

Comment: @Ktash: The stock market's existed for over 11 years... Like, it was created, I think, within three years of Neopets launching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.neodaq.com/charts/charts.php) looks like it might be the list you are looking for.